# Call to undefined method InvalidArgumentException::getJsonBody()

Tags: stripe, charge

I'm having an issue with Charge (v. 1.9.2) running on EE (v. 2.10.1). Whenever I try to process a test payment, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method InvalidArgumentException::getJsonBody() in /system/expressionengine/third_party/charge/models/charge_stripe_model.php on line 894
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed with [Charge 1.9.4](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/expressionengine/charge/log#release-charge-1.9.4)